# VB 2015 Login Form "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to code a login and registry program within VB.Net

However. I now need to create the login aspect, I don't usually ask around for help. I usually look up, but I've hit a wall and I have no idea what to do.

This is part of a subroutine that is supposed to read all lines in the text file and put userName and passWord into the array position.

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(userAccount) = True Then
       Dim i = 0
       Dim userArray() As String
       Dim userLine As String
       Dim fileReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(userAccount)
       Do While fileReader.Peek <> -1
           userLine = userLine & fileReader.ReadLine()
           userArray = userLine.Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           For i = 0 To UBound(userArray)
               MsgBox(userArray(i))
               userName(i) = userArray(i * 2)
               passWord(i) = userArray((i * 2) + 1)
               txtUsernameLogin.Text = userName(i)
               i = +1
       Loop
```

However. I'm having issues with this code.

```
userName(i) = userArray(i * 2)
passWord(i) = userArray((i * 2) + 1)
```

Is creating the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

First thing I did to resolve this was, well just look up solutions and frankly, I can't find any solutions.

How do I fix this? I have no clue what to do.

Comment: Why are you multiplying `i` by 2? Also, you need to show us the declaration of `userName` and `passWord`.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this. I am going to assume you have a text file with the usernames and passwords delimited with a "|" character, yet you are joining the previous 'userline' with the next 'userline', and then trying to parse the whole thing again, with no delimiter to separate each entry from the last, the second line will include the first, and so on. Why are you not just parsing the next 'pair' of values? You also have no `Next` following the `For' and no bounds checking. 'userarray' is useless because it not certain if the array contains actual pairs of values. Crazy.